# Android Button drawableLeft - how to hardcode it (no xml)

Tags: android, button, drawable

How can I add a "drawable left" icon to a button object?

I mean something like this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setDrawableLeft(R.drawable...);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(..)` which relates to [android:drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) attribute.